# powershell -Certificate on php

Tags: php, powershell, azure, curl, azure-web-app-service

Hello I have this powershell working:

```
$dnsname = "xxx.yyy.cat"
$cert = get-childitem -path cert:\currentuser\My\* | where Subject -eq "CN=$($dnsname)"
$subscriptionID = "25b92657-61a3-4dd1-bada-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$url = "https://tenantpublicapi.xxxxx.cat"
$webspacename = "defaultwebspace"
$websitename = xxxxx

$webrequest = [string]::Format('{0}/{1}/services/webspaces/{2}/sites/{3}',$url,$subscriptionID,$webspacename,$websitename)

(curl -Uri $webrequest -Certificate $Cert -Method Get).content
```

I need to do this with php but i cant make de curl call work with certificate:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=> 2,
CURLOPT_CAINFO=> getcwd() . "/xxxx.xxxx.cat.crt",
CURLOPT_SSLKEY=> getcwd() . "/xxxx.xxxx.cat.key",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT=> 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2',
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://tenantpublicapi.xxxxxxx.cat/25b92657-61a3-4dd1-bada-xxxxxx/services/webspaces/defaultwebspace/sites',));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

print_r($resp);
```

Any idea on what I'm missing?

Comment: `CURLOPT_CAINFO` -> `CURLOPT_SSLCERT`

Comment: I still get: {"Code":"ClientCertificateNotFound","Message":"The request does not contain a client certificate that is registered for the subscription.","Details":[]}1

Comment: Could you try this post http://www.binarytides.com/use-clientside-ssl-certificate-curl-php/? Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT That worked perfectly !